# How to plot separate pens for a turtles-own variable

Tags: netlogo

All of my turtles have a turtles-own 'distance-travelled variable' and I want to plot how this changes for each turtle on the same graph. I know I could state which turtle ie

```
ask turtle 0 [plot distance-travelled]
```

But the nature of my model means that the user can change the number of turtles so I can't pre-emptively write in which ones to plot.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `create-temporary-plot-pen`, so you can have one pen per turtle.